# When and why should I use $b^2 - 4ac$ (discriminant)?

Tags: quadratics, discriminant

When should I use the discriminant ($b^2-4ac$) and why would you use it in such a question:

[image: Question here (didn't let me embed)]

Comment: In (iii) there is **exactly one** solution (corresponding with "tangent"). This means that the discriminant must equal $0$ in that case.

Comment: @drhab, Oh I see, but what's the reason behind using b^2-4ac in this case?

Comment: A part of the information in (iii), ("the line is a tangent to the curve") is translated into equation (discriminant$=0$) and this equation allows you to find $a$. That knowledge is welcome.

Comment: @drhab, Aha, that makes sense. Alright thank you! :-)